# Widget and Blink Feed

Tags: feature-request, android-app

I would really like a widget that shows you answers and new comments for your questions. Also a HTC-BlinkFeed option would be nice (I don't know if this has to be done by HTC, I'm not a android Developer)

Comment: The inbox widget could probably work as a feature request, but the BlinkFeed is too localized as it's exclusive for SenseUI, and doesn't worth the time.

Answer (score 2):

> I would really like a widget that shows you answers and new comments for your questions.

You could check the inbox for new comments and answers to your own questions so really that has already been applied here. There shouldn't be anything new; this is good enough for our needs for now.

> Also a HTC-BlinkFeed option would be nice (I don't know if this has to be done by HTC, I'm not a android Developer)

This is what BlinkFeed is: BlinkFeed lies at the heart of HTC's Sense UI, bringing news and social updates to your home screen. [Source](http://www.androidcentral.com/blinkfeed). Stack Exchange isn't some type of website that has social media or a news service. We ask and we answer (and moderate and do cool stuff). We don't offer news or give updates of your Facebook account. We don't do that here. Period.

So for me, these requests are useless and already been applied (not for the BlinkFeed though).